# Why is Wernike's area of the brain called Wernike's area?

Tags: neuroanatomy, psychology

My teacher told us that this area of the brain helps with the comprehension of language and it is located in the temporal lobe of the cortex, but she never told us why is was called Wernike's area and she told us it might be on the AP Exam. So why is it called that?

Comment: http://bfy.tw/2CPD

Comment: Anything specific you were looking for you couldn't instantly find on google?

Answer (score 7):

As often the case, named after the person who first described it.

[From Encyclopedia Britannica](http://global.britannica.com/science/Wernicke-area):

> Wernicke area, region of the brain that contains motor neurons involved in the
>   comprehension of speech. 
>   This area was first described in 1874 by German neurologist Carl
>   Wernicke.